# how to get country by user Ip address in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the login-ed user country by his IP . The first function get ip address .

```
 public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
 {
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
}
```

the second function  takes ip and return country

```
 public static string GetUserCountryByIp(string ip)
    {
        IpInfo ipInfo = new IpInfo();
        try
        {
            string info = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://ipinfo.io/" + ip);
            ipInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpInfo>(info);
            RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo(ipInfo.Country);
            ipInfo.Country = myRI1.EnglishName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ipInfo.Country = null;
        }

        return ipInfo.Country;
    }
```

the problem here is the second function doesn't return any data . when i tried my IP at https://ipinfo.io/IP it return bogon=true .

how can i return not bogon ip.

Comment: From the tags, it looked like you were running that code in ASP.NET. What do you expect your server region to be, other than where you already know it is?

Comment: I need function that return IP , from that Ip i can get all data (country,city)

Comment: You need the user's IP, not your server's IP. Please [edit] your question, and either remove the [tag:.net-core] tag (if you're using ASP.NET) or change the [tag:asp.net] tag for the [tag:asp.net-core] tag (if you're using ASP.NET Core).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to get the client's IP location, you need to use the client's IP address and not the hosts. To do this in ASP.Net Core you can do:

```
var clientIpAddress = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

From there you can use clientIpAddress as the IP passed to your GetUserCountryByIp function.

Comment: what is the namespace of Request?

Comment: it return {::1} what is this ??!!

Comment: Because you are trying it locally, ::1 is localhost

Comment: Deploy the site and test it

Comment: Request ("r">>>"R")